# how many members are there in this set?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

how many members are there in this set?

$\{x \mid x\in  \mathbb Z\,-2+\frac{\sqrt{2251}-15\sqrt{10}}{2}<x<7+\frac{12\sqrt{20}-\sqrt{2879}}{2}\}$

with calculator I find the answer $9$ but without calculator I cannot do anything.

Comment: You could estimate the square roots and work from there. For example 2251=47*47+42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n = 2250$. Then,

$$-2 + \frac{\sqrt{2251} - 15\sqrt{10}}2 = -2 + \frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}2 = -2 + \frac1{2 (\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt{n})} \in (-2, -1)$$

Similarly, the rightmost number is in $(7,8)$.

Therefore, $x \in \{-1, \ldots, 7\}$. So we have $9$ solutions.